# VS Code Insiders prints debug logs when opened via command prompt

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am seeing some logs (seems to be internal logs for debugging purposes) when I open vscode-insiders(%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\Code - Insiders.exe) from command-prompt (cmd.exe)

[image]

What is the setting/configuration using which I can disable this logs?

If this setting/config is not exposed then can this be planned to add/fix in upcoming release?